# Load data from separate kafka cluster to Samza?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-samza

I am trying to create a Samza job that as closely resembles the Wikipedia example job as I can make it.  However in the "WikipediaFeed" object I am trying to get data from a different Kafka broker than the Kafka broker that is running when you start the Hello-Samza grid.

Do I have to create a thread safe Kafka consumer inside the "WikipediaFeed" object to consume data from a different Kafka cluster or is there another way I'm not seeing?

Edit 1:
Here is a link to their Wikipedia example.
https://github.com/apache/samza-hello-samza/tree/master/src/main

Thanks

Comment: can you link the Wikipedia example ?

Comment: @MaximeF  Added.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Just to be sure, your question is you want create a Samza to consume 2 different Kafka topic and one Kafka topic is on Cluster 1 and the second is on the cluster 2 ?

Comment: Right, so I have a fronting Kafka cluster that get's data pushed to it and a Samza cluster that has it's own internal Kafka instance.  I want to pull data from the fronting Kafka cluster into the Samza Kafka instance so I can do work on it.

Comment: so your Samza will consume only one Kafka topic right ?

Comment: No, it will need to consume multiple topics.

Comment: Your Samza run into Cluster 1 who consume 1, 2 or 10 Kafka topics from cluster 2 right ?

Comment: Correct.  Cluster 1 is a co-located Samza/Kafka/ZK and wants to consume multiple topics from a separate three node kafka cluster.

Comment: I edit my post below.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you need change this config (https://github.com/apache/samza-hello-samza/blob/master/src/main/config/wikipedia-feed.properties) :

```
systems.kafka.consumer.zookeeper.connect=KAFKA_CLUSTER_FRONTING:2181
systems.kafka.producer.bootstrap.servers=KAFKA_CLUSTER_FRONTING:9092
task.inputs=kafka.topic1,kafka.topic2,kafka.topic3
```

Change the config with your Fronting Kafka cluster
and add your topic in task.inputs separated with ","

Edit:
Just to be clear, you can deploy your Samza into a Cluster 1 and consume a Kafka topic from another cluster. You need change the config in your Samza properties.

To see more information : [Samza config](https://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.12/jobs/configuration-table.html)

Then if you need send your message after process to another Kafka cluster you will need create another system in your config.

See more information : https://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.13/api/overview.html

Comment: If I set the kafka system to my fronting cluster will my output streams exist in my Samza instance?

Comment: Yes but it's more complex.